# How to disable angular cache in nx repo?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I created nx project with angular preset.

How can I disable angular cache in nx?

I known there is option `--skip-nx-cache`, but this is a different cache (it's nx cache). I talk about `.angular` folder cache (`ng cache disable`).

The problem is I can't run `ng` command because it's not accept the same arguments that `ng` does.

So, How I can disable the cache?

Answer (score 4):

I'm work with angular 13 and expecting it will work 14, 15(cli options are still same).

Update `project.json` file of your project as below.

```json
{
    "cli": {
        "cache": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    ... already exist...
}
```

Please remind, `.angular`(cache folder) should delete manually.

Also, I found an [issue(Angular 13 ng cache support #10150)](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10150)  related with this.